# jQuery .blur function isn't working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

jQuery `.blur` function isn't working.

```
$("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var date = Date.parse($(this).val());
        if (isNaN(date)) {
            //some code
        }
    } else {
        //some code
    }
});
```

There are no errors occurring in the browser...it just doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you put code in document.ready and successfully included jQuery?

Comment: Any errors in the console perhaps ?

Comment: or just set handler after element beeing added in DOM or use delegation for dynamic element

Comment: Are you attempting to use `blur` on an HTML label?

Comment: @Adil Yes, I put this in ready and the jquery is included correct, but the problem persist.

Comment: @Chris Hardie is a textbox,The name is incorrect

Comment: @Nacho Is this code in an ASP.Net page or a javascript file?

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov No error in the consule, I try debug but no enter in the event

Comment: @ChrisHardie Technically speaking blur on a label is ok: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents

Comment: @Chris Hardie the code is in asp.net page ("MyPage.aspx"). The control is a textbox

Comment: Check the format of the date is coming.

Comment: @Anand Thangappan not think that's it, since no errors, and when I try debug the event is not fired.

Comment: Give this a shot, just curious if it's going to work: `$('input[id^="txtDate"]')`

Comment: Can you also post the code from the View Source screen?

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov  not working :(

Comment: @Nacho Sorry my bad, actually it should be: `$('input[id*="txtDate"]')` I wasn't sure how WebForms creates the Id's, try this one with the `*`

Comment: your code is correct only, Need more code to check, May be case of updatepanel, dateformat, Textbox id or serverside event fire like textchanged..

Comment: ok, a minute, I'm doing some tests, many thanks to all for your responses.

Comment: Now it works, the problem was in another javascript that interfered with the same control. Thank you very much for the answers, were of tremendous help to realize that this code was correct. Thank you again. (sorry for my english)

Comment: @Nacho you may facing some javascript/ jquery related error in your code. Please show whole code so that we can easily identify the problem. I have tried your code is it running properly. http://jsfiddle.net/8zc7Y/1/

Comment: @Manoj Mevada Read my last comment, I already solved the problem, anyway thank you very much. As I can put this question as resolved? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in another javascript that interfered with the same control. Thank you very much for the answers, were of tremendous help to realize that this code was correct. Thank you again. (sorry for my english)